# Responsive site, unresponsive on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, responsive-design

The following page scales down in a desktop browser when the viewport is decreased

http://rocoru.com/blog/

However, when viewing from the iPhone itself, the desktop version is still shown regardless

why might this be?

Comment: your responsive check needs to be done prior to body loading !

Comment: On an unrelated note, why is your site content shown only on the right of my monitor?  60% of the space, including the bit I'm looking at in the center, is blank.

Comment: not sure which browser and OS your using? The site does however purposefully float: right;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

You can get some more information about this tag and why you need it by googleing
"viewport meta tag"

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your media queries for mobile.

```
.excerpt .entry p {
overflow: hidden;
}
```